# Выборка по двум полям

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток! есть таблица:

```
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `MarketId` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `Sum` double NOT NULL,
  `ItemId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL
```

Как выбрать все строки, в которых содержатся уникальные значения `uid` и `ItemId`?

Comment: А что конкретно нужно? Именно уникальные _комбинации_ двух полей? Или только уникальные значения каждого поля?

Comment: Уникальные значения каждого поля

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следующий запрос даст вам 2 строки с уникальными значениями.

```
select * from table where id in (
    select id from table where uid in (select uid from table group by uid having count(uid) = 1)
    )
    and id in (
    select id from table where ItemId in (select ItemId from table group by ItemId having count(ItemId) = 1)
    )
)
```

Если это не то что нужно то добавьте коментарий в котором приведите пример, пару строк из базы и то что хотелось бы получить в результате.

Comment: Нужно вот что:
1. выбрать все записи с уникальным значением `uid`
2. выбрать все записи с уникальным значением `ItemId`
3. выбрать все записи из таблицы, где `Id` в диапазоне значений `Id`
уникальных `uid` и `ItemId`

Comment: @woland, уникальные = неповторяющиеся? (потому что иначе это все записи)

Comment: тоесть если uid или ItemId повторяются то нас такие строки из БД не интересуют?

Comment: @ICE - да.

Comment: select * from table where id in (
select id from table where uid in (select uid from table group by uid having count(uid) = 1)
)
and id in (
select id from table where ItemId in (select ItemId from table group by ItemId having count(ItemId) = 1)
)

Comment: то, что надо

Comment: рад был помочь)